# Convert file to byte array in reverse order

Tags: java, android

```
byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];

FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
fileInputStream.read(bFile);
fileInputStream.close();
```

This code let's me convert file to byte array, am looking for reading file from end to start (in reverse order)

Edit : i dont wan't to read entire file. A part at the end (Example around 1000 bytes)

Comment: Why don't you just use the data in the byte array in reverse order? Since it's in an array you're free to do as you please with it.

Comment: yeah but i just need only a part of file length at the end

Comment: Ah... See, that's important information. What you are asking is if there is some way to read the data at the end only and not the beginning also?

Comment: reading whole file and reversing the byte array will take soo much memory , may even throw out of memory exception. I need to perform this task for many files

Comment: @blahfunk exactly, sorry for incomplete question.. I need a read a part of file at the end (may be around 1000 byte)

Comment: The file is only 1000 bytes total?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://crunchify.com/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-reverse-order/

Comment: Let me give an example, I have an mp3 file of some 5mb, I want to read last 1000 bytes of the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
File file = new File(/*file path*/);
byte[] bFile = new byte[1000];

RandomAccessFile fileInputStream = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
fileInputStream.seek(fileInputStream.length() - bFile[0].length);
fileInputStream.read(bFile, 0, bFile.length);
fileInputStream.close();
```

I just figured it out, reading last 1000 bytes of a file